# Can't prevent default on form submission | Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

*Using Vue 3.0.5*

I have a form:

```
<form id="app" @submit="onSubmit">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And a Vue component:

```
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

And can't seem to prevent the page from reloading on form submission. In the version above, I use `e.preventDefault()` in the method. I've also tried:

- `@submit.prevent` instead of manually calling `e.preventDefault()`
- `v-on:submit` while calling `e.preventDefault()`
- `v-on:submit.prevent` without calling
- `@submit.prevent`/`v-on:submit.prevent` and manually calling at the same time

Nothing seems to work except reverting to Vue 2. Perhaps an issue with Vue 3 or some quirk I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A workaround is to wrap the `form` in another element, such as a `div`, and use that as the mount point:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      console.log('submit')
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the button type as button and just do a on click event to do what you want. That should prevent it from reloading

So something like:

```
<form id="app">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" @click="yourFunction">submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem is in your button type. If you want, you can also prevent default on the button instead of the form.

Comment: That's a decent side-step, but doesn't prevent the user from just hitting enter to submit. In which case the page reloads and values are lost.

Comment: Then if that is the case, then you can just add prevent default on the click event of the button. That should stop the reload of the page

Comment: With one of the input fields focused, a user can press the enter key and the submit event will fire. They don't have to click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@submit.prevent` without the `e.preventDefault()` ..vue2 & 3 both version will handle the event propogation automatically..

Since this is a Comman event call vue takes care of this for us.. and also because `methods()` as suppose to be used data logic rather than DOM manupilation

Ref - [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: Yep, I've tried that (second half of the question).

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
    <form id="app" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "App",
        data() {
            return {};
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

This works correctly. The default is prevented `@submit.prevent="onSubmit"` like this.

Tested on vue3 app.

Comment: It looks like you're using a single file component here. I'm just mounting a Vue app instance. If your version does indeed work with 3.0.5, i'm thinking this might be a Vue issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using **Vue 3** with the **Composition API**.
Note that this example uses `<script setup>` and node.

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const formName = ref('');
const formEmail = ref('');
const formMessage = ref('');

function submitForm(){
    console.log(formName.value);
    console.log(formEmail.value);
    console.log(formMessage.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
     <input v-model="formName" type="text" >
     <input v-model="formEmail" type="text">
     <textarea v-model="formMessage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In one project I am working on using vue 3.2.37, I have tried everything OP tried and cannot prevent page reloading. I have used @submit.prevent in other projects successfully.

My workaround was to add a listener to the input as well to provide the submit on enter functionality.

```
<input type="password" v-model="state.password" @keydown.enter="authenticate" />
<button @click="authenticate">login</button>
```